# Can not find symbol using private method "defaultAnswer()"

Tags: java, string, methods, substring

There is a "Question" class which are designed to create questions for users.

checkAnswer method of the Question class is designed for taking response which does not take into
account different spaces or upper/lowercase characters. For example, the response
"abcd" should match an answer of "A b Cd".

> /**
>          A question with a text and an answer.
>        */

```
public class Question
{
   private String text;
   private String answer;
```

> /**
>             Constructs a question with empty question and answer.
>          */

```
   public Question() 
   {
      text = "";
      answer = "";
   }
```

> /**
>             Sets the question text.
>             @param questionText the text of this question
>          */

```
   public void setText(String questionText)   
   {
      text = questionText;
   }
```

> /**
>             Sets the answer for this question.
>             @param correctResponse the answer
>          */

```
   public void setAnswer(String correctResponse)
   {
      answer = correctResponse;
   }
```

> /**
>             Checks a given response for correctness.
>             @param response the response to check
>             @return true if the response was correct, false otherwise
>          */

```
   public boolean checkAnswer(String response)
   {
      response = response.toLowerCase();
      for(int i = 0; i <= response.length() - 1; i++)
      {
         if(response.charAt(i) == ' ')
         {
            response = response.subString(0, i) + 
            response.subString(i, response.length());
         }
      }

      response.equals(answer.defaultAnswer());
   }
```

> /**
>             Displays this question.
>          */

```
   public void display()
   {
      System.out.println(text);
   }

   public void displayAnswer()
   {
      System.out.println(answer);
   }

   private String defaultAnswer()
   {
      answer = answer.toLowerCase();
      for(int i = 0; i <= answer.length() - 1; i++)
      {
         if(answer.charAt(i) == ' ')
         {
            answer = answer.subString(0, i) + 
            answer.subString(i, answer.length());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Java and JavaScript are different languages, so I've removed the "JavaScript" tag from this question, but both languages are **case sensitive**.

Comment: it `substring` not `subString`. Method name is all lowercase in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using methods `subString()` and `defaultAnswer()` that are not defined for `String` class.

- The first one actually seems like a typo. Replace it with `substring()`.
- For the second one - you have defined the method, `defaultAnswer()` for the `Question` class and the variable, *answer* is of `String` class. You can fix this by replacing `response.equals(answer.defaultAnswer());` with -
  `response.equals(this.defaultAnswer());`